# Meaning of "avere la botte piena, la moglie ubriaca e l'uva sulla vigna"

Tags: meaning, proverbs, idioms

Can anyone explain what *avere la botte piena, la moglie ubriaca e l'uva sulla vigna* means?

Also, are there regional variations of that proverb? If so, what are they?

Comment: regional variations in plain italian or in any of the italian slangs?

Comment: @Giuseppe, sorry I don't understand your question; can you rewrite it in plain English? Thank you.

Comment: For the record, I've _never_ heard it including the third part, just the first two.

Comment: @KyriakosKyritsis in Italy there are a lot of regional slangs and sometimes you can find variations of a proverb in a specific regional slang. When you ask for "regional variations", are you looking for variations in "official" italian or variations in "regional slang"?

Comment: A friend of mine used to say "avere la botte piena e la moglie bottana", but I don't think it qualifies as an "official" variant. :-/

Answer (score 12):

It has the same meaning of the expression "*have your cake and eat it too*", that is, when there's a tradeoff you cannot have both things at the same time.

In this case you have three parts:

> botte piena = a full barrel [of wine]
>   moglie ubriaca = a drunk wife
>   uva sulla vigna = grapes on the vine, the grapes used to  make the wine

The third part is sometimes omitted, and you also have *avere la moglie piena e la botte ubriaca*.

There are some regional variations, for example, in Ferrara there's *an s'pol brisa aver galina, ov e cul cald* (*non si possono avere gallina, uovo e culo caldo*; literally, "you can't have chicken, egg and warm ass," where *warm ass* means not to have to work).

Comment: Maybe it depends on the region, but often "avere la moglie piena e la botte ubriaca" is a funny joke on the phrasing of "avere la botte piena e la moglie ubriaca".
"Moglie piena" commonly means "pregnant wife", and sometimes "botte ubriaca" means that the wood of the barrell is soaked with wine from previous stockings, and it could give a worse taste to new wine.

Answer (score 3):

It means to want something impossible, since it is not possible to have a barrel full of wine if somebody drank the wine, and it is not possible to have grapes on a grapevine, if the grapes have been used to make wine.

The only variant I know is the shortened version of what you wrote: *Avere la botte piena e la moglie ubriaca*.

Answer (score 0):

Much simpler: it is pretending or willing to have one's wife already drunk while having the barrel of wine still full for having all desires fulfilled.
In (Argy) Spanish: "tener la chancha, los veinte (lechones) y la máquina de hacer chorizos".